# Unpacking array values

Tags: python, list, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to unpacking this array        [[[[0.07338447]] [[0.92661554]]]]

I've found a way to do it but it is quite inefficient.I'm looking for more efficient to solve this.
Thank you.

```
i = 0
myres = [[[[0.07338447]] [[0.92661554]]]]
for  value in enumerate(myres[0]):
    print("value", value)
    for value1 in enumerate(value[1]):
        for count, value2 in enumerate(value1[1], 100):
            print(count, value2)
            print("value2", value2)
            print("I value", i)
            if (i == 0):
                ageValue = value2
                print("ageValue", ageValue)
            else:
                GenderValue = value2
                print("GenderValue", GenderValue) 
            i = i+1
```

Comment: Could you please specify what you're expecting the end-result to be? Is the order or depth important for the end result?

Comment: convert to a numpy array and use flatten: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html

Comment: Sure, I'm trying to retrieve those two floating values separately.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a flat list out of list of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-to-make-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import numpy as np

myres = [[[[0.07338447]], [[0.92661554]]]]
arr = np.array(myres).flatten()
val1, val2 = arr
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `numpy` or just loop it simpler like this:

```
myres = [[[[0.07338447]],[[0.92661554]]]]
for i in myres[0]:
    print(i[0][0])
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use recursion:

```
data = [[[[0.07338447]],[[0.92661554]]]]

output = []
# function used for removing nested lists in python
def removeNestings(l):
    for i in l:
        if type(i) == list:
            removeNestings(i)
        else:
            output.append(i)
    return output

print (removeNestings(data))
```

output:

```
[0.07338447, 0.92661554]
```

or just with list comprehension:

```
def removeNestings(l):
    return sum(([x] if not isinstance(x, list) else removeNestings(x)for x in l), [])

print(removeNestings(data))
```